# Why FFMPEG's -movflags faststart parameter makes empty files when output is over network drives?

Tags: ffmpeg

I made an application that uses ffmpeg to compress video files. There are 3 computers crunching the files from and to a Synology NAS.

Everything works great, but if I add the parameter "-movflags faststart" the resulting file ends being 0Kb.

The same commands works well if output file is on local hard drive.

I need this parameter to move the moov atom at the begining so making the file suitable for progressive download.

Comment: You need to check verbose/log output: there should be `av_log` entry explaining the failure.

Comment: I don't see any error in logs but exit code is 1

Answer (score 0):

I have seen problems in the past getting accurate stats/seeks of files on file servers. Similar behavior could be stopping ffmpeg from doing its job. Can you adjust your app to pull the files down to the local drive for ffmpeg processing? I don't know that you'd loose much time, if any, since ffmpeg would probably need to read/write just as many bytes over the network.